# Can i use Global System Hooks to capture which file was clicked on?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am new to Windows programming, mostly done Java(Java SE, Java ME, Android, Java EE), so be detailed and gentle.

I want to capture "the name of the file/path that was clicked in windows, like clicking a file on the desktop"?

Further research http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET, which is a small c#/c++ nice app that uses Global System Hooks, to capture mouse events such as coordinates,clicks,etc.

So what is the right API or Global System Hook that captures events on file icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single API that provides that level of detail.

The `WH_MOUSE` and `WH_MOUSE_LL` hooks of `SetWindowsHookEx()`, or the `WM_INPUT` message delivered by `RegisterRawInputDevices()`, can tell when the mouse is being intereacted with, and the `GetCursorPos()` function can tell you where the mouse cursor is located onscreen at the time of a click, but it cannot tell you what it is clicking on. You have to figure that out manually.

For instance, the Desktop is implemented as a ListView control, so you can use the `WindowFromPoint()` and `GetDesktopWindow()` functions to check if the mouse is located at coordinates corresponding to the desktop window itself instead of an application window, and if so then use the `LVM_HITTEST` and `LVM_GETITEM` messages to determine which icon onthe desktop is being clicked on and extract its display text.  Then use the `SHGetDesktopFolder()` function and the `IShellFolder` interface, or the `SHParseDisplayName()` function, to parse that text and see if it returns a `PIDL` that represents a path/file, and if so then use `SHGetPathFromIDList()` to get the actual path/file name.

If you want to do the same thing with the Windows Explorer app, it gets a bit more complicated.  Use `WindowFromPoint()`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, `OpenProcess()`, and `EnumProcessModules()` to determine if the mouse is over the Windows Explorer app.  However, its UI changes from on Windows version to the next, but the jist is that you have to manually locate the focused control via `AttachThreadInput()` and `GetActiveWindow()`, check if it is a TreeView/ListView control, and if so then use control-specific messages to get information about the item/icon underneath the mouse cursor coordinates, and use `IShellFolder` again to figure out what the text of that item/icon actually represents.

Shell programming is very complex system and not for the feint of heart to interact with.  So you need to ask yourself, why do you need this information in the first place?